# create PHP yii framework code documentation

Tags: php, documentation, yii1.x

What is the simplest tool to create a useful code documentation for web appliaction based on Yii 1.1 framework (that used PHP language).
I need a manual way not auto generating tool, and I need something simple to use like Word and not something needs cmd or any console to create the documentation.
I hope my question is clear this time :)

Comment: Clearly this post is seeking recommendations for **tools**

Comment: @kenLee yes of course